# Erro quando ativa um tema no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Toda vez que adiciono um tema no WordPress da o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in public_html/wp-content/themes/StyleShop/epanel/core_functions.php on line 9

O WordPress está na versão mais nova, em localhost o tema funciona perfeitamente mas quando coloco no servidor ele dá esse erro.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Pesquisei sobre o erro mais não encontrei nada referente ao `core_fuctions.php`.

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido quando fiz um tema para um cliente, eu procurei muito, e consegui resolver, ainda bem que eu consegui resolver rápido, esse erro pode ser por causa do UTF-8 com BOM.

Para Resolver isso, use o Notepad++ e Mude de UTF-8 para UTF-8 SEM BOM

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas quase todos editores de texto possuem essa opção

Comment: O que tem na linha 9 do seu core_functios.php? Posta o código pra gente ver!